# Bootstrap Collapse Navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying for the past couple of hours, but a simple thing don't seem to be working. As you know Bootstrap provides for collapsible navbar when on smaller screens. However this functionality doesn't seem to be working for me.

Here is the concerned code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container">

            <button class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>      
            </button>

            <button class="navbar-toggle pull-right btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navForm">
            Sign In/Sign Up
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navHeaderCollapse pull-left">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about-us.php">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="privacy-policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="sitemap.php">Sitemap</a></li>
                    <li><a href="blog" target="_blank">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" id="navForm">
                  <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
                  <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#signin" data-toggle="dropdown">Sign In <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;" id="signin">
                        <form action="[YOUR ACTION]" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                            <input id="user_username" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="text" name="user[username]" size="30" />
                            <input id="user_password" style="margin-bottom: 15px;" type="password" name="user[password]" size="30" />
                            <input id="user_remember_me" style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" />
                            <label class="string optional" for="user_remember_me"> Remember me</label>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary" style="clear: left; width: 100%; height: 32px; font-size: 13px;" type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign In" />
                        </form>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

The jsfiddle is:
http://jsfiddle.net/n94zL/

**Update:** I am getting the following error in Firefox Dev Tools
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

What could this mean?

Comment: Including bootstrap-collpase.js are we?

Comment: There's no seperate file called 'bootstrap-collapse.js'. However, I am including bootstrap.js. But Firefox Dev Tools show this error: Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Comment: Actually, there is collapse.js exclusively for collapsing elements but since you use the bootstrap.js package, collapse.js is included along with other small plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few errors that needs to be corrected to have your navbar working:

1) Some of Bootstrap elements/widgets use jQuery library (which actually is a JavaScript library). So, make sure you include the jQuery library (bootstrap needs it).

2) bootstrap.js (or bootstrap.min.js) is needed too

3) You should be targeting `data-target="#navHeaderCollapse"` (note the `#`) because it is the  `id` and not a `class`

As for the jQuery library, you can either download it from [here](http://jquery.com/download/) or link to the live .js file:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Note that the above line should come before you call your  bootstrap.js

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a55X7/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot still get it to work for me in my localhost, nor in my fiddle. Can you please check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n94zL/3/)

Comment: @user3736335 You were targeting the `<ul>` element, whereas you should be using `data-target` on the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">`. No idea why you removed the `id="navHeaderCollapse"` from there but that's correct. Updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/n94zL/4/). Feel free to ask if you need more help.

Comment: I was targeting `<ul>` because that's what I intend to do. I want the menu to open up when I click the menu icon and a signin form to open when I click the 'Sign In/ Sign Up' Button.. Is that possible?

Comment: That would work. So you just removed the div and it worked? Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user3736335 Strike the old one because the form doesn't load. You could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kDXU9/) instead. What I did was, apply the `collapse nav-collapse` classes to the `<ul>` and removed the divs they were previously on, and for showing the form, your anchor tag `href="#signin"` should be `href="#"`

Comment: Can you just help me in one more thing? Suppose a user has clicked the menu. After that if he clicks the sign in/sign up or just clicks anywhere else on the page, the menu should itself close, as happens on most websites. I know that would involve tweaking the JS, but I am not adept at JS.

Comment: @user3736335 Is **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/hg6Ag/)** what you are looking for? The jQuery bit basically checks if the `in` class is present in the `<ul>` element on every click by the user, if it is present, it removes that class thereby closing the element.

Comment: This is exactly I am looking for. How do we implement it?

Comment: @user3736335 Umm implement what exactly? Well to get this working on your machine, you need to make the HTML changes, jquery library, bootstrap.js and copy the **[jQuery code](http://pastebin.com/LReCc0Fh)** I wrote at the end inside `<script></script>` tag.